# PDFKit gestures issue stop working after upgrade to IOS 13

Tags: gesture, ios13, pdfkit

I've developed an app for iPad that use Apple PDFKit to show and add annotations to PDF.
The app works correctly on all the IOS system (from 11.0 to last 12 vrs).
Now on device that has IOS 13 installed the app has troubles on gesture and there's nothing to do to solve.
Any ideas about what is could be happen and if this will be solved with a new build of IOS 13 (may be 13.2....)?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution of PDFView touches cancelled called after upgrade iOS to 13.+
need to add this line.. 
self.pdfview.documentView?.gestureRecognizers?.removeAll()

Comment: Would please help me and look at my question too if you solve this problem please ?stackoverflow.com/questions/58609831/… Thank you very much

Comment: GREAT!!!! To mantain compatibility backward i've added:         if #available(iOS 13, *) {
            pdfView.documentView?.gestureRecognizers?.removeAll()
        }

Answer (score 0):

In my case issue is with the Xcode version 11.1. Update your mac OS to 10.15.1 and Xcode to 11.2. I hope it will resolve the issue.

Wish you goodluck!!

Answer (score -1):

I empathize with you and have exhaustively searched for an answer. It is clear that simulators and iPhones running IOS 13 up to and including 13.2 beta do not respond to PDF gestures (i.e. tap on hyperlink(s) does not activate the hyperlink to fetch/display the URL. IOS 12.4 and less all work fine.

So here is what I have found:

1) This defect occurs with all PDF documents made with Adobe or other pdf generators such as omnigraffle or any pdf downloaded from the internet.

2) You can take the unresponsive pdf (which has been compiled within Swift 5 etc. and export it to Notes and its links will work however once displayed in a compiled Swift app running under IOS 13 13.1.2 or 13.2 beta the links no longer respond. Once you change the IOS back to 12.4 all works well.

3) Interestingly if you take one of the unresponsive links' url and make a button within Swift and ask its action to display the url and compile the App and press the button the URL/link will be displayed properly.

I believe as does omnigraffle staff that this is an issue to be solved between Adobe and Apple.

Comment: @Carlo Cicchi do you find any solution

Comment: Would please help me and look at my question too if you solve this problem please ?stackoverflow.com/questions/58609831/… Thank you very much

Comment: @MidDev Would please help me and look at my question too if you solve this problem please ?stackoverflow.com/questions/58609831/… Thank you very much